# ServiceStack RequestLogger shows past requests as "is running" long after being issued

Tags: servicestack

I am running ServiceStack 3.97 and just added the RequestLogger plugin - amazing that it is built-in, just what I needed.  The worrisome thing I noticed once I tried it is that it says all the previous GET requests have "**is running = true**".

For example, I issued a few requests in a browser tab (pressing F5 a few times, and closed tab) and can see them show up here /api/requestlogs.  In the items column, the elapsed time keeps ticking each time I refresh and is running is always true.

This is very scary as it appears to be saying that the requests remain open.  If so, it could be related to an unknown error I get over time whereby SS is unable to return an Open connection.

Here is a sample of the items field:

```
_request Duration Stopwatch
    is Running true
    elapsed PT8M31.5460178S
    elapsed Milliseconds 511546
    elapsed Ticks 1395611107
```

Any suggestions or ideas as to why this is happening and/or how to dig deeper?  What would keep GETs open?

Comment: I don't think that it is related. The code of [RequestLogsService](https://github.com/mono/monkeywrench/blob/master/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Admin/RequestLogsService.cs) is here. it does not involve StopWatch or message like "is Running true". Request Logger is an optional plugin from contributors. In the ServiceStack source, the StopWatch is used in  Tests and Profiler. I don't think you should be worry.

Comment: to correct my previous comment, the code it seems to be in [ServiceRunner](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Host/ServiceRunner.cs#L58) if RequestLogger  is running. It is in the AfterEachRequest event of the ServiceRunner. I think, without to be sure, that the Request is not ended yet, in this point, or the text did not updated. It does not seem  real problem, hope the team to correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **RequestLogger** takes a 'snapshot' which includes a dump of the **Request.Items** dictionary (which contains a Stopwatch) into a rolling log of DTO's, but this doesn't keep the request 'open' as you might think, so there's no need for concern.

Comment: Thanks - was worried that somewhere a call to Close (on request) and Stop (on the stopwatch) was missing.